# git collaborate on branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, collaboration

Tom and Alice would both to collaborate on a branch of `project`, which is hosted on Github.  Here is what happened so far:

1. Tom forks `project`.
2. Tom makes branch `new-feature` in his fork.
3. Tom commits changes to `new-feature`.
4. Alice forks `project`.
5. Alice: `git remote add toms-fork git@githum.com:Tom/project.git`.
6. Alice: `git fetch toms-fork`.
7. Alice: `git checkout toms-fork/new-feature`

   Note: checking out 'toms-fork/new-feature'.

   You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

   If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

   git checkout -b

So, this has confused Alice (me).  Do I need to make my own branch and submit a PR to Tom to merge into my branch into `toms-fork/new-feature`, which will then be merged into `project`?

Also, why is Alice (me) in a `detached HEAD` state?  Why am I not on `toms-fork/new-feature`?

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You checked out the remote tracking branch called `toms-fork/new-feature`.  This left you in a detached HEAD state, which isn't want you want.  Instead, you probably intended to do this:

```
git checkout toms-fork/new-feature
git checkout -b alice-branch         # create a new branch from new-feature
```

Then, do all your work on this branch, and when it comes to merge your work back into `new-feature`, you can issue a pull request on your `alice-branch`.  This assumes that you want to share `new-feature` with your collaborator Tom.  If you want your own branch, you could also have created one in the `project` fork directly from the `master` branch, e.g.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b alice-branch
```

Then, both Tom's and your branches would eventually be merged back into `project`.

Comment: ", you can issue a pull request on your alice-branch." How do you do this part?  Is it a PR to toms-fork/new-feature..?

Comment: _You_ tell _me_ the answer to that question.  If you want your work to go into `new-feature`, then issue a PR with that as a destination.  If you want it to go back to `master`, then issue a PR for that.

Comment: Creating a pull request is a two-step process.  First, _push_ your branch to GitHub via `git push origin alice-branch`.  Then, from within the GitHub site, create a pull request and choose the destination you want.  That's it.

Comment: Ooh, ok.  Thanks Tim, I think I did this correctly just now.  Appreciate your help.  While learning I have a tricky time separating git from Github sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You are in detached HEAD state when you checkout to `toms-fork/new-feature` is caused by the branch `toms-fork/new-feature` is not your locally branch.

If you and Tom are collaborate for `toms-fork/new-feature` branch, you and Tom can use on the same github repo, such as `git@githum.com:Tom/project.git` (If it’s ok for both of you).

For private reason, you can’t have the permission of Tom’s github repo. So you need to create your local branch and submit a PR to Tom. Then Tom submit a PR to project (or both of you can submit PR to `project`).

If your local changes need to based on `toms-fork/new-feature`, you can use below steps:

```
# on master branch
git checkout -b mybranch
git rebase toms-fork/new-feature
make/commit/push your changes to toms-fork and submit a PR
```

Comment: Why rebase as opposed to merging?

Comment: Usually rebase is opposite with merge. Such as on `b1` branch, use `git rebase b2`, it will replay the change from `b1` on to top of `b2`. But if `b2` is not local branch, rebase is different.